# How strong is a titanium coated bit?

Tags: drill-bits

How strong is a titanium coated bit? Some people say that it can not be sharpened by a diamond file or a grinding wheel while others say yes. How much longer does a titanium bit last compared to other bits? like HSS, or carbon oxide?

Comment: This might be hard to answer since there are different titanium bits and it depends how you would be using it and on what materials.

Comment: Sort of, I did ask that question for the comparison but I am curious about how it is against everything else.

Comment: Have you tried researching the rockwell hardness of all the materials you're looking to compare? This would give you a good sense of comparison.

Answer (score 3):

As one of the comments has already touched on this is actually impossible to answer. It's a "How long is a piece of string?" question.

> How much longer does a titanium bit last compared to other bits? like HSS, or carbon oxide?

This sounds a bit like you're under the impression that "titanium bits" are made from titanium, in case you are: they're not. They're merely coated with a titanium compound (these days, primarily titanium nitride which is a brassy colour).

Titanium nitride is I think fairly uniform in properties, but the bits to which it is applied are anything but. It's actually widely reported that the coating on consumer-level bits is the go-faster stripe of the drill bit world, made to attract the eye of buyers but with no promise of anything in terms of quality.

Even if the questions was "How strong are TN-coated HSS bits?" it's still unanswerable because there are multiple versions of HSS, and heat-treating for even a single type can result in different end properties same as it can for basic carbon steel (hence the differences in hardness and brittleness between a vintage chisel and a vintage screwdriver, both of which are typically made from exactly the same steel).